# Flair is not displaying for me

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, flair

Well, last day, I try to use flair in my profile and it's work properly.
Today, the flair is not displayed and I don't know why.

The flair is rendered like this:

> profile for Iswanto San at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers

It's a alt attribute in img src, means that the image can't be found.
I try to copy the image url and paste that in my browser (firefox):

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1210760.png

And it give me:

> The image “https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1210760.png” cannot be
>   displayed because it contains errors.

In IE9 it give me:

The website cannot display the page

> HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

[image]

What happen with this?

What I have tried so far.

1. Try using another PC.
2. Clear cache, cookies and active login in my browser.
3. Using another browser (IE9)
4. Disable all firefox add-ons

Anyway, after add the flair in my profile, I download the [Stack Alert add-ons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-alert/). But I don't think this will cause the problem, since I've tried in another PC and browser.

Comment: Strange, works for me.

Comment: right floated content looks strange else its fine in your profile and in link you given

Comment: I try to remove all information from my profile and only put the flair..but it's still doesn't displayed

Comment: There is an internal server error (HTTP 500) when the browser try to download the image...

Comment: This loads fine for me, both the URL you provided and your flair in this and your SO profile. Are you perhaps having issues with other elements on pages not loading?

Comment: @TimPost: No, the other elements is working properly

Comment: What happens when you go to http://stackexchange.com ? And when you browse to your profile page?

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bGXs7.png) one?

Comment: @hjpotter92: yes, it's my flair!

Comment: @Oded: I can open stackexchange.com but when I browse to my profile page, the flair doesn't happen. It's only show the text like I described in my post..

Comment: I just give more information in my question..

Comment: I have had no problem in any of the following: Opera 12, Chrome 25, Firefox 18 and IE 8.

Comment: I've tried to disabled all my firefox add-ons and it's still doesn't work for me

Comment: So, Iswanto, are you saying [the copy](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bGXs7.png) @hjpotter92 posted does NOT give you any problems? That works fine for me on a Mac, and also in IE9 on Windows 7 (in Parallels on a Mac). hjpotter92's copy is, however, slightly different from [a copy](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oM7qk.png) I grabbed right now, which works fine for me too.

Comment: It is not showing the flair PNG for me. Also a 500 error. I'm on IE9. One number down and up flairs are working fine...

Comment: @IswantoSan and @rene - can you please confirm whether this is still an issue? ``

Comment: @Oded: Thanks!, it's work now..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you were hitting NY-WEB03, as I took at look at all our web servers - the locally cached gravatar on all of them was fine, except NY-WEB03, where it was a 0 sized file.

This is likely to cause the issue you have seen (and explains why most people are not seeing the issue).

I have deleted the file and this should sort our the flair issue as well.